# Wordpress: SVG file is not being loaded from CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a css that loads a SVG image from a folder. But this image is not being loaded in the site.

Do I need to do extra configurations in wordpress in order to load an SVG from a css file?

Comment: In Chrome devTools network tab, what is the status of the SVG image failing to load?

Comment: No, the image is not failing in the load

Comment: So the SVG has a 200 status and on the website, it's like an image with a broken source?